# Create React App not reusing existing tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, macos, create-react-app

I have been developing a web app (for a few months) that is built on top of [CRA](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app). Everything has been working as intended until this morning when I realized that the npm (or yarn) start script is no longer reusing the existing tab I have open in Chrome. It instead opens a new tab at localhost:3000 even if there are existing tabs at localhost:3000. I have been investigating this for a few hours but am yet to find a solution. I added a log statement in the CRA script (within my node modules) that handles the reusing of existing tabs upon startup of the app.

```js
function startBrowserProcess(browser, url) {
  // If we're on OS X, the user hasn't specifically
  // requested a different browser, we can try opening
  // Chrome with AppleScript. This lets us reuse an
  // existing tab when possible instead of creating a new one.
  const shouldTryOpenChromeWithAppleScript =
    process.platform === 'darwin' &&
    (typeof browser !== 'string' || browser === OSX_CHROME);

  if (shouldTryOpenChromeWithAppleScript) {
    try {      
      // Try our best to reuse existing tab
      // on OS X Google Chrome with AppleScript
      execSync('ps cax | grep "Google Chrome"');
      execSync('osascript openChrome.applescript "' + encodeURI(url) + '"', {
        cwd: __dirname,
        stdio: 'ignore',
      });
      return true;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      // Ignore errors.
    }
  }
```

This is the output of the log statement:

```js
{ Error: Command failed: osascript openChrome.applescript "http://localhost:3000/"
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
    at execSync (child_process.js:658:13)
    at startBrowserProcess (/Users/***/Desktop/WorkSpace/React/***/node_modules/react-dev-utils/openBrowser.js:78:7)
    at openBrowser (/Users/***/Desktop/WorkSpace/React/***/node_modules/react-dev-utils/openBrowser.js:122:14)
    at Server.devServer.listen.err (/Users/***/Desktop/WorkSpace/React/***/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:100:7)
    at Server.returnValue.listeningApp.listen (/Users/***/Desktop/WorkSpace/React/***/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js:604:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at emitListeningNT (net.js:1328:10)
    at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 2691,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null }
```

It seems to have an issue running the Applescript command that handles this but I am unsure why. One of the other developers that is working on the same app locally is not having this issue. One change I made recently was upgrading to the new macOS Mojave. But the other developer just upgraded as well and is not having this issue.

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out after I upgraded Mojave I denied interface access to Google Chrome from my terminal. So it was unable to run the "reuse" tab script.

Comment: How did you manage to fix this? Am running into the same annoying issue

Answer (score 1):

To avoid opening a new tab,
you'll need to create an .env file in the root of your project and add this line,
BROWSER=none.
As shown [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2084#issuecomment-299357398)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to grant your terminal access to your browser

macOS Ventura 13.2.1 path:

```
Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Automation -> Terminal -> Google Chrome
```

the environment variable for disabling this feature at all:

```
BROWSER=none
```